# Font size changing with refresh in html

Tags: html, css, font-size

I am using google chrome in android and when I refresh the page in the font size increases and after refreshing it goes back to normal. It happens randomly when refreshing.

The only thing I can notice in my page is that I have this code in my webpage:

```
<div style="border-left: 2px solid; height: 55%; float: left; margin-top: 20px;">
</div>
```

If I remove this code than the problem takes place.

What is causing this and what is the solution to this?

Comment: If you remove the in-line styling of that DIV the problems appear?  And the problem is your text possibly being too large?

Comment: @NathanChampion Yes, the problem is still persisting after removing in-line styling of the DIV.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the view port tag: 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
And when you set the size of things in css use vw as the unit for example:

```
p{
font-size: 2vw;
}
```

If this doesn't work it might be a chrome issue.
check out this article for resizing issues:

[Link to article](https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s10-s10-plus/952894-text-size-changes-randomly.html)

Answer (score 0):

Usually when this happens, it is due to font substitution.  It's likely that you are using a web font, which must be downloaded before it can be used.